# WPS office spreadsheet scripting?

Tags: wps-spreadsheet

Is some additional scripting available for WPS office spreadsheets? I need to upgrade by application platform from Apple numbers, it supports formulas and very limited automation scripting which is stored outside document, to something where can I build more complex applications.

I need ability to define my own functions and manipulate cells (such as changing background color)

Answer (score 1):

The old version of Kingsoft Office Pro used to have a VBA add-on.

However, WPS Office does not support it.

See WPS for
[Best Practices for Securing Documents](https://blog.wps.com/best-practices-for-securing-documents/):

> You should always use caution opening unknown documents—with and without VBA/Macros. (Older versions of WPS Office offered full support for VBA/Macro, and may try to automatically open these files.)